# A timed state machine, does this work?

Tags: java, concurrency

In jave i have a state machine which i need to migrate to automated state changes, in this i mean i need state changes to occur after certan intervals.. for instance after 5 seconds state one, after 10 seconds state 2.

I was thinking of using ;

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
```

Schedule a task that basically calls a method, which would change state and then schedule another task to change to next state, and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it might work.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes i did, it kinda worked. Just doesnt seem to feel right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need code similar to this:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // TODO: do something
        }
    }, 
    0, // no wait and start the 1st one
    5, // delay 5 seconds and do the next one
    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You could also look into scheduleAtFixedRate().